# Church tax back payment when leaving

Tags: germany, taxes, religion

I've started working in Germany two years ago. During the anmeldung I declared that I don't belong to any religious organization. I am an atheist, but I was baptized in Poland. I thought that saying no in the anmeldung form is enough, but recently I've learned about ​Kirchenaustrittserklärung and I've started to worry about backpayment. I would like to leave church officialy.

Will I need to pay all of the taxes from my anmeldung to the day I declare that I'm leaving the church in Standesamt?

Comment: What is your nationality?  Polish?  I don't know about Germany, but in Sweden the equivalent of Kirchenaustrittserklärung is only relevant for people born into the Swedish church.

Comment: Did you pay Kirchensteuer? (it's on your payment paper) If not, then there's nothing to get paid back. If yes, then you won't get anything paid back anyway.

Comment: I'm not paying it. I'm afraid the **I** will need to pay back the tax when I leave the church.

Comment: You should be more worried on stating untruth in official papers. An interesting issue. You could claim that, because of separation of state and religion in Poland, there is no official leaving of the church, and therefore the effective situation (you being an atheist) should become an official one when entering the Germany...